# How to enable TLS security (https) for Hyperledger Explorer and Hyperledger Composer endpoint URLs?

Tags: hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

I have enabled TLS (https) for Hyperledger Composer Rest Server APIs. However I dont find any articles for enabling the TLS for **Hyperledger Explorer** endpoint URL and **Hyperledger Composer** endpoint URL.

[Hyperledger Explorer endpoint URL exposed on port 8080 without TLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS4aW.jpg)

Could I find is there a way to enable TLS to these URLs

Comment: When you say Hyperledger Composer endpointURL do you mean Composer Playground ?

Comment: Yes.. I mean composer playground

Comment: I can't answer for hyperledger explorer but it isn't possible directly in playground. It's not recommended that you try to provide a hosted playground yourself. The one on the ibm cloud runs in a way to only enable the web browser profile and also uses the capabilities of ibm cloud to expose an https endpoint